# What would be a better way to code this if then else clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, logic

I have the following code. I'm still a newbie in Ruby on Rails. As you can see I'm repeating myself 4 times.

I tried something like this:

```
if @property.nil? || @property.status_id == 144 || (@property.status_id <= 16 && current_user.nil?) || (@property.status_id <= 16 && current_user.id != @property.user_id)
```

But it gives me lots of errors in case @property is nil. Because then @property.status_id cannnot be called since @property is nil.

Anyway, I think an experienced Ruby on Rails coder gets the idea.

```
  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
    if @property.nil?
      flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    if @property.status_id == 144
      flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    if @property.status_id <= 16 && current_user.nil?
      flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    if @property.status_id <= 16 && current_user.id != @property.user_id
      flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
      redirect_to root_path
      return
    end
    @images = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>{:property_id => params[:id]})
  end
```

root

Comment: Normally you wouldn't need to have the show page handle nil values. How could someone get to the show page for a property if it doesn't exist in the first place?

Comment: You should be combining your tests with `&&` and `||`, that's what they're for.

Comment: @beerlington this is a website for a real estate broker. Old properties are deleted from the table, making visitors with older links get an error. You have a point, maybe they should not delete old properties. Anyway, it's a safeguard.

Comment: that makes sense. What is the `current_user.nil?` logic for then? Are users deleted with properties too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that really the exact code? || [short-circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and a nil value shouldn't be a problem.

```
@property=nil
if @property.nil? || @property.status_id == 144
   puts @property.class.to_s
end
```

Outputs
`NilClass`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and indeed, it seems that it is indeed short-circuited. So I added the complete line with all ||'s and &&'s and it works. Don't know why I got an error on it yesterday. Maybe it was before I addes the rescue nil.

Answer (score 2):

```
def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id]) rescue nil
    if @property.nil? || @property.status_id == 144 || (@property.status_id <= 16 && (current_user.nil? || current_user.id != @property.user_id))
      flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @images = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>{:property_id => params[:id]})
    end
  end
```

I am not familiar with Ruby syntax so this might not really compile, but you get the idea.

Comment: Hi Vlad, I tried something similar I think, see my one line of code. Issue there is that @property.status_id gives an error in case @property is nil. Then I call a method on a nil value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should approach this by defining the "can show" logic into a straightforward helper method you can call to make a determination rather than cluttering up your show method with all kinds of branches that ultimately make the same action occur.

```
def can_show_property?(property)
  return false unless (property)

  return false if (property.status_id == 144 or property.status_id > 16)

  return false unless (current_user && current_user.id == property.user_id)

  true
end

def show
  @property = Property.find(params[:id]) rescue nil

  unless (can_show_property?(@property))
    flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
    redirect_to root_path
    return
  end

  @images = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>{ :property_id => params[:id] })
end
```

Having "magic" numbers in your code like 144 does lead to asking why they aren't assigned constants. It's usually a lot easier to understand when clearly labelled `MyApp::PROPERTY_LOCKED`.

Comment: thanks, this is indeed a better way, turns out I can also combine all conditions in 1 line. I wasn't yet aware of the technique with Constants. I looked it up, it is indeed way better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def show
begin 
  @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  if [144,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0].include?(@property.status_id)
    flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
    if current_user && (current_user.id != @property.user_id)
      redirect_to myimmonatie_path 
    else
      redirect_to root_path 
    end
rescue
  flash[:error]=t("The_property_was_not_found")
  redirect_to root_path
end
@images = Image.find(:all, :conditions =>{:property_id => params[:id]})
```

end

Comment: Oh common, I know `include?` is very Ruby, but what's wrong with `if @property.status_id == 144 || @property.status_id <= 16`?

Comment: ((0..16).to_a << 144).include?(@property.status_id) would be a little more readable perhaps. Not sure it is preferable to meager's comment though.